# How to store Data in MyClass:Hub

Tags: c#, signalr, store, signalr-hub

I'm making a project using signalR and I would like to store some data such as:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> UserAndConnectionId;
```

If the user is disconnected and reconnected, his **connectionId** will change and I would like to set his interface depending on his activate group.

So, I created this class:Hub and some functions :

```
public class MyClass: Hub
{
    private Dictionary<MyFirstObject, List<MySecondObject>> _reference { get; set; }
    private int _count;

    [HubMethodName("onConnected")]
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnConnected");
        List<MySecondObject> userList;

        _reference = new Dictionary<MyFirstObject, List<MySecondObject>>();
        userList = new List<MySecondObject>();
        userList.Add(new MySecondObject("userId", "userName", Context.ConnectionId));
        _reference.Add(new MyFirstObject("groupName", null), userList);

        _count++;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    [HubMethodName("onDisconnected")]
    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnDisconnected");
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    [HubMethodName("onReconnected")]
    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnReconnected");
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

Obviously, each new client will call the **onConnected** function and the

```
_reference = new Dictionary<MyFirstObject, List<MySecondObject>>();
```

will erase all data each time.
So I also tried to increment an **int _count**.
And when I read the **Debug.writeLine("Count:" + _count);**, I can see that the **int _count** is reset each time.

Do you have an idea to store temporarily some data such as the **`Dictionary<string, string>`** in MyClass ?

Answer (score 5):

I found on multiple asp.net example my solution:

```
private static Dictionary<MyFirstObject, List<MySecondObject>> _reference { get; set; }
```

I just had to add the **static** attribute to let the **_reference** in memory and usable throw the groups calls.

The example was found on : [asp.net/signalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections)
when the authors talk about the following code :

```
private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = 
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();
```

I hope it will help other :)